# User Relationships, Many to Many

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I need to create relationships between users. As you might expect, they exist in the `users` table. My approach is a `relationships` table linking `user_a_id` to `user_b_id`.

Then, in the `User` model, I added:

```
public function relationships()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'relationships', 'user_a_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error when trying to find the relationships;

```
dd($user->relationships);
```

Output: *Whoops, looks like something went wrong.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider something like a "user" model, and a "group" model. The users table can have a many-to-many relationship with the groups table, and this could be defined with a "user_group" table, containing a column "user_id" and another "group_id". Then you can have a function in your User model called groups, which does return $this->belongsToMany('Group');, and a function in your Group model called Users, which goes return $this->belongsToMany('User');

Refer to [this](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many) section of the Eloquent docs for further direction.

Comment: So if `user_a` is friends with `user_b`, I would need to create a group called `User A B Friendship` (or something), and assign only those two users to it?

Comment: Sort of yeah, basically to do many-to-many relationships between two tables, you simply need a third table which contains (at least) two columns which refer to the ID's of the related tables. You could also store additional information about the relationship if you want (such as a name or description), but that is up to you.